# GUI Testing With Network

Tags: unit-testing, testing, gui

I am doing GUI tests for my network application and I'm wondering if I should stub out mock responses, or if it's OK to keep using the network for the GUI tests.

It seems to me the main benefits of stubbing the responses are:

1. Speed
2. Robustness - no false errors because of network problems

And the cons are:

1. Server interaction (real world) - doesn't test this
2. Time to implement and maintain mock up (for a large application)

Are the pros worth the cons? Are GUI tests about testing the actual application and if it runs for a real user connected to the server, or are they more similar to regular unit tests, but for the GUI - are they just trying to test the GUI and don't care about server interaction.

**EDIT**

This question specifically relates to GUI tests, not regular unit tests, and is questioning the value of stubbing mock responses in the GUI tests vs. using the server normally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need unit test if I already have integration test?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/204786/do-i-need-unit-test-if-i-already-have-integration-test)

Comment: Yes, the question I linked to is more general, so it is not a suprise it includes yours, and the topmost answer applies to yours as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unit tests are for testing your code, not real-world scenarios. Specifically, unit tests should validate that your code produces correct outputs for given inputs. Nothing more.

Server latency and responsiveness are certainly worth testing, but not with *[unit tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)*. Those would be covered by *[system tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_testing)*.

The risk of relying on networking for unit tests is they may fail due to problems outside the scope of the *unit of code* being tested. If you have a [CI server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) with automated unit testing (you should), your build might fail if e.g. MIS takes the remote server down for maintenance. That is a false negative: the failure indicates a problem in your code, when the problem is an unresponsive server.